# How to prevent Microsoft Word from changing my equations in LaTeX?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

Currently, I'm trying to write some formulas in Word using LaTeX. However, every time I save the Document and re-open it, I find my formatting changed.

For example, I have the equation `\mathbf{F} : U \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n`

The first thing that should be noted is that `\mathbb` isn't working as intended either, as it doesn't display the wanted character that is supposed to denote "real", it simply shows capital R.

The second thing is, the bolded F completely disappear after I close the document and re-open. It just becomes F instead.

Comment: Might help if you mention versions of apps, e.g., MS Word (on Windows, I assume?)

Comment: Apologies, yea I am using Microsoft 365 Word on Windows. It's Version 2309.

Comment: Please edit your question to add such useful information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/equations-reformatting-when-saved/420c6be0-7900-43e7-aac9-25a5e7cf1806) in older versions of Word which they supposedly fixed. Since you mentioned that you are using Office 365, you might want to report this again.

As for the real symbol, please note that the MS Word LaTex editor doesn't fully support all LaTex commands. You will have to nest the unicode syntax inside the vector `\mathbb{\doubleR}`

Comment: I see, came across this post as well. Looks like I'll just have to deal with it somehow. Thanks for the insight!